# Disable scanner programmatically in DataWedge

Tags: android, datawedge

Actually i use `Output Intent` from `DataWedge` to send decoded data to my application, so in the application there is recorded a BroadcastReceiver which get the decoded data

```
private BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (Objects.equals(action, getResources().getString(R.string.activity_intent_filter_action))) {
            //  Received a barcode scan
            try {
                displayScanResult(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //  Catch if the UI does not exist when we receive the broadcast
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The question is is it possible in some way disable the scanner without using EMDK? 
I would be able to disable the scanne if the following condition is true:

```
 if(Alerts.dialogError != null && Alerts.dialogError.isShowing()){
            // Here i should block the scanner
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways, the easiest of which being:

```java
Intent dwIntent = new Intent();
dwIntent.setAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
//  Enable
dwIntent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SCANNER_INPUT_PLUGIN", "ENABLE_PLUGIN");
//  or Disable
dwIntent.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SCANNER_INPUT_PLUGIN", "DISABLE_PLUGIN");
sendBroadcast(dwIntent);
```

For more context, I just wrote a developer article about this at https://developer.zebra.com/blog/quickly-suspend-scanning-your-app-datawedge

Answer (score 0):

The general API documentation is available at: https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/latest/guide/api/

The documentation for the scanner input plugin is here: https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/latest/guide/api/scannerinputplugin/

As of DataWedge 13.0 the following code is used to enable/disable the scanner input plugin:

```
private void enableScanner() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
    i.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SCANNER_INPUT_PLUGIN", "ENABLE_PLUGIN");
    i.putExtra("SEND_RESULT", "true");
    i.putExtra("COMMAND_IDENTIFIER", "MY_ENABLE_SCANNER");  //Unique identifier
    this.sendBroadcast(i);
}

private void disableScanner() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
    i.putExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SCANNER_INPUT_PLUGIN", "DISABLE_PLUGIN");
    i.putExtra("SEND_RESULT", "true");
    i.putExtra("COMMAND_IDENTIFIER", "MY_DISABLE_SCANNER");  //Unique identifier
    this.sendBroadcast(i);
}
```